# How does AppCompat inflate layouts that do not explicitly use AppCompat widgets?

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat, layout-inflater

It occurred to me while using AppCompat, that I had been using things like `Button` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton` within my layout XML files. I did a test, via `view.getClass().getSimpleName()` and confirmed that even though I declared it as a `Button` in the XML, the class being loaded was in fact `AppCompatButton`.

How does this work, under the hood?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the process of researching this topic in order to ask the question correctly, I discovered the answer myself.

When using `AppCompatActivity`, some interesting things happen:

1. A `LayoutInflater.Factory` is applied to the default `LayoutInflater`, via `setFactory`. The `AppDelegateImpl` classes within AppCompat implement the `Factory` interface, and one of them is chosen as the factory delegate depending on the API level. There is also a slightly different `Factory2`, targeting later APIs.
2. When your views are being inflated from XML, the name of the view's class is passed into the `Factory`'s `createView` method, which is given the opportunity to override the actual view that is created.
3. The name of the view is checked against a hard-coded hash table of strings in `AppCompatViewInflater`, and if a match is found the view is inflated by the delegate, instead of the default inflater.

Comment: You can even override the inflater in your theme. AppCompat has this: `<item name="viewInflaterClass">androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater</item>`. MaterialComponents theme uses this to inject its own custom layout inflater. At least since support library 28, don't know how it worked before.

Comment: What if you wish to do it manually (example is when you inflate something and notice that the library isn't being used) ? Or even wrap what's of the library?