# Android: Is there a simple way to create rounded corners for a view without having to create a separate drawable each time?

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components, android-shapedrawable

I have gone through various solutions on the internet, which enable us to create views with rounded corners. Most of them require the use of creating custom views, or to create a drawable in xml or a nine-patch each time we need a rounded corner view.

The problem is that when I implement such views, I need to create a drawable for every such view, even if two views have everything but just the background color in common. This is kind of irritating for me and I've heard the iOS framework provides a good way to create round cornered views. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: Along with rounded corners, the press effect of a view and shadows are also among the common styles used. Please let your solution include those effects.

Comment: Have you tried `CardView`?

Comment: I did, but it's only a view group, and not a proper solution to this issue.

Comment: Maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692236/8906488) answer for Android API > 21

Comment: you can create your custom imageview with rounded corners and use it wherever you want

Comment: @NehaRathore I understand that, but I'm just looking for a solution that is generic and convenient across all views. Also, please point out a few links that explain how you ease this process as an answer. Much appreciated:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the Material Components Library you can use the [**`MaterialShapeDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) to [draw custom shapes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md).

For example with a **`TextView`** you can do:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/secondaryColor"
        ../>
```

Then create a `MaterialShapeDrawable`:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
        .build();

MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
ViewCompat.setBackground(textView,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

With a simple **`View`**:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/..."/>
```

Then apply the same `MaterialShapeDrawable`:

```
View line = findViewById(R.id.line);
ViewCompat.setBackground(line,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

You can also create different corners:

```
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,0)
    .setBottomRightCorner(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
    .build();
```

[image]

Also most of the components provided by the [Material Component Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) have a MaterialShapeDrawable as background.
In these cases just use something like (in this example a MaterialCardView).

```
  MaterialCardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.card);
  cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setBottomLeftCornerSize(...)
        .setBottomEdge(...)
        .build());
```

It requires the version **1.1.0** of the library. Currently `1.1.0-beta02`.

Comment: Thank you, I feel this is the best solution thus far. I suppose you can also add shadows and press effects this way

Comment: @Harsha I've update the answer with an useful link for the [shaping](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md).  Here the [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) for the MaterialShapeDrawable.

Comment: This is nice, may I ask how you keep yourself updated on the various methods of doing stuff on android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gradient drawable for your views programmatically and can set that view as background

```
 GradientDrawable getRoundedCornerView(int shapetype,int color,float radius){
     GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
     shape.setShape(shapetype); //GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE for rectangle
     shape.setColor(color);
     shape.setCornerRadius(radius);
retrun shape;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to change the color of the background, you can use `backgroundTint`

For example:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        app:backgroundTint="#F00"
        />
```

Please note: I'm using `app:backgroundTint` here, by using `app` prefix, AppCompat Views (AppCompatImageView, AppCompatButton, etc) can read this attribute and tint the background on pre-lollipop Android devices, but you should make sure you are using appcompat library.

**The universal solution:**

On second thought, I come up with a method: you can create a [`LayoutInflater.Factory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.Factory) and replace all the views(imageView, TextView, etc) with your own custom view which takes corner radius and color as background, [just like AppCompat library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575093/how-does-appcompat-inflate-layouts-that-do-not-explicitly-use-appcompat-widgets).

Comment: Hi Zumi, I'm not sure how a background tint can help with rounded corners.

Comment: Well, you said "even if two views have everything but just the background color in common"in your question so I thought all your view will have same radius but with different color.

Comment: Then you can create one rounded corner drawable as background and use backgroundTint to control the background color of the view.

Comment: Oh, maybe that can help. There could be some alpha composition done when a tint is used though. Thank you.