# How do I modify radius of specific view's corners programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

I've seen different approaches on how to design a view with rounded corners. However, what if I want to make this kind of view **reactive** and change the radius of some of its corners at some point? In another words, I would like to be able to modify corner radius of each corner programatically. As an example, I want to be able to make top-left corner of the view rectangular on some event and then make it rounded again on another one.

I know that maybe there are out-of-box solutions, but I am deeply interested in implementing it myself.

It would be great if at some point I am able to write something like `myView.topLeftCornerRadius = 10f`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59046711/android-is-there-a-simple-way-to-create-rounded-corners-for-a-view-without-havi/59054785#59054785

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti that is a good one and I have already had a look on it. But maybe is there a way to implement such drawable/view without using material?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to avoid the use of the material components? Nowaday the great majority of apps use it

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti not a great reason, but it is simply a research interest. I most likely will be using material for this, on another hand It would be great if I was with provided some knowledge about how to do it myself